# HOW to Allow user to select and upload multiple file in a prticular folder and get path of the folder in java

Tags: java, path, wicket, multiple-file-upload

Hi Guys i am a beginner in java. I am currently working in apache wicket which is a java based framework. I am trying to create a load button to select and upload multiple files in a particular folder. I already have this piece of code using which i am able to select and upload a single file but i am confused doing same selecting and uploading multiple files.

Thanks in advance

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {

 private FileUploadField fileUpload;
 private String UPLOAD_FOLDER = "C:\\";

public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {

    add(new FeedbackPanel("feedback"));

    Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("form") {
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit() {

            final FileUpload uploadedFile = fileUpload.getFileUpload();
            if (uploadedFile != null) {

                //write to a new file
                File newFile = new File(UPLOAD_FOLDER
                        + uploadedFile.getClientFileName());

                if (newFile.exists()) {
                    newFile.delete();
                }

                try {
                    newFile.createNewFile();
                    uploadedFile.writeTo(newFile);

                ///file which is diplayed after uploading
                info("" + uploadedFile.getClientFileName());
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Error");
                }
            }

        }

    };

    // Enable multipart mode (need for uploads file)
    form.setMultiPart(true);

    // max upload size, 10k
    form.setMaxSize(Bytes.kilobytes(1000));

    form.add(fileUpload = new FileUploadField("fileUpload"));

    add(form);

}
```

}

Comment: I think you need a `MultiFileUploadField`... See here: http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/upload/MultiFileUploadField.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is `MultiFileUploadField`, but note that it allows you to select some files only one by one. (open dialog->choose file->press 'open'->open dialog->choose file...).  Working example [here](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/upload/multi). Click "source code" link to see...source code.

There is also HTML5 solution, which allows you to select multiple files at once. [Here](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/upload/single) it is, the last one. Note that it won't work in html version < 5.

And no, you can't fetch parent folder path, because of security issue. (it's not about wicket, this is about web development).